# Move the Smallest and largest to head and tail of linked list

Tags: java, linked-list

How to return a Linked list with head as minimum element and tail as maximum?

The function `shiftSmallLarge()` takes the head node of a linked list as a parameter and returns the head pointer after doing both shifts.

```java
static Node shiftSmallLarge(Node head){
 if(head==null){
  return null;
}
  Node temp=head;
  Node min=head;
  Node max=head;
  while(temp.next!=null){
  
    if(temp.data<min.data){
      min=temp;
    }
    if(temp.data>max.data){
      max=temp;
    }
    temp=temp.next;
  }
  
}
```

Comment: You will need to keep track of the nodes pointing to the max and min too, so that you can snip them out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get previous node in linked list by making two pointers initialize one pointer from null and other from head of list. Iterate other node which you initialize from head till the node which you want and iterate the first node before the 2nd node.

Answer (score 0):

Do it in O(n). traverse through the link list. Find two nodes(Smallest node & Node previous to the smallest node). Likewise find two more nodes(largest node and node previous to the largest node). Now make the smallest node as the head and adjust the continuity of the link list as you have the node previous to the smallest node. Likewise adjust the largest node at the end as you have the largest node and the node previous to it.

Comment: how do i get to previous node in singly linkedlist?

Answer (score 0):

I think the below code will work but it is too big .I can't able to reduce it.if you got better idea please correct me.

```py
def shiftSmallLarge(head):
    if not  head or not head.next:
        return head
    pre=None
    minpre=None;maxpre=None
    mini=head;maxi=head
    curr=head
    while(curr):
    if curr.data<mini.data:
        minpre=pre
        mini=curr
    if curr.data>maxi.data:
        maxpre=pre
        maxi=curr
    pre=curr
    curr=curr.next
    if mini==head and maxi==pre:
    return head
    elif minpre==None:
    maxpre.next=maxi.next
    pre.next=maxi
    maxi.next=None
    return head
    elif maxpre==None:
    if maxi.next==mini :
        pre.next=maxi
        head=head.next
        maxi.next=None
        return head
    head=head.next
    minpre.next=mini.next
    mini.next=head
    head=mini
    if pre != mini:
        pre.next=maxi
    else:
        minpre.next=maxi
    maxi.next=None
    return head
    else:
    minpre.next=mini.next
    mini.next=head
    head=mini
    if maxpre==mini:
        minpre.next=maxi.next
    else:
        maxpre.next=maxi.next
    pre.next=maxi
    maxi.next=None
    return head
```

Answer (score 0):

**Move the Smallest and largest to head and tail of list**

- This code works well for this problem

```
// Return the head of updated list
    static Node shiftSmallLarge(Node head) {
      // Write your code here
      if(head == null || head.next == null) {
        return head;
      }
      Node temp = head;
      Node min = head, max = head;
      // find minimum node and maximum node
      while(temp != null) {
        if(min.data > temp.data) {
          min = temp;
        }
        if(max.data < temp.data) {
          max = temp;
        }
        temp = temp.next;
      } 
      // if min is at head do not anything with min
      if(head != min) {
        // finding previous node of min
        temp = head;
        while(temp.next != min) {
          temp = temp.next;
        }
        temp.next = min.next;
        
        // add min to start of list
        min.next = head;
        head = min;
      }
      
      // finding previous node of max
      temp = head;
      while(temp.next != max) {
        temp = temp.next;
      }
      temp.next = max.next;
      
      // add max to end of list
      temp = head;
      while(temp.next != null) {
        temp = temp.next;
      }
      max.next = null;
      temp.next = max;
      
      return head;
    }
```